# "Думаю, что точно..." - это верно?

Tags: семантика

***Думаю, что точно [завтра будет дождь]...***

~1. Верна ли такая конструкция логически (или семантически)?
~2. Если да, то что она означает?
~3. Если нет, то существует ли похожая верная конструкция (можно с заменой "думаю" и "точно" на синонимы или синонимичные обороты) и каков будет её смысл? 
~4. Зависят ли ответы на 1 и 2 от того, что стоит в квадратных скобках?

Прошу по возможности отвечать именно на эти вопросы и с примерами, философствовать можно только для объяснения ответа.   
Спасибо.

//=============== 
С Марком Изом я уже поговорил )))
Хотелось бы еще мнений. Желательно - независимых.

> Мысль взята отсюда

а) Не вижу там таких мыслей. Даже отдаленно похожих.
б) А вообще - личное мнение автора, сиречь ахинея. Разбирать конкретно не буду, ибо а).

Answer (score 3):

1. Да.
2. Моё мнение (не претендующее на абсолютную истину) - завтра наверняка будет дождь
3. Таких конструкций много.
4. По большому счёту, нет.

В русском языке, есть семантическое различие между правдой, которая у каждого своя, и истиной, которая одна на всех. Конструкции вроде, *я думаю, что точно*, говорят о том, что человек уверен в том, что его утверждение правда, но на истину не претендует.

Comment: ~2. Тогда зачем "думаю"?  
~3. Примеры?  
~4. "Я думаю, что точно ответил на вопрос только [Марк Из]". - ?

Comment: 1. Подчеркнуть, что это личное мнение, а не абсолютная истина, не подлежащая сомнению. Я уверен, что Бога, таким каким его представляют христиане не существует, но так как прямых доказательств отсутствия у меня нет, указываю, но то, что это мои рассуждения, а не научный факт.
3. *Я считаю, что наверняка эти примеры найти можно*.
4.  Вполне возможная конструкция. :-)

Comment: ~1 Подчеркнуть, что это личное мнение...  
  
А без этого чье бы было мнение? Собственно, мы уже и уперлись...  
Хорошо, давйте с другой стороны.  
Есть ли разница в конструкциях "Я думаю, что депутат N - жулик и подхалим" и "Депутат N - точно жулик и подхалим". "Есть ли разница" - ну хотя бы юридически. А в "behemothus точно назвал депутата N - жуликом и поджхалимом" и "Я думаю, что behemothus назвал депутата N жуликом и подхалимом"?

Comment: >Я считаю, что наверняка эти примеры найти можно.   
  
Это уже не интересно. Мне хотелось понять, что Вы **называете** такими примерами, а не тог, что из можно найти.

>Вполне возможная конструкция. :-)   
  
Аналогично. Мне смысл конструкции интересен. Как вы её понимаете и почему. Это был контрпример к Вашему предыдущему высказыванию, отнюдь не самоочевидному, которое Вы тем не менее ничем не подкрепили. 
Я-то вижу большую разницу в двух вариантах ("...точно пойдет" и "...точно ответил").

Comment: *"Я думаю, что депутат N - жулик и подхалим"* - личное мнение, юридически не наказуемо.

*"Депутат N - точно жулик и подхалим"* - утверждение, которое при отсутствии оснований, может послужить причиной иска за клевету.

*"behemothus точно назвал депутата N - жуликом и подхалимом"* - Если behemothus не называл, подать иск может он на автора, если называл - на него может подать депутат N.

*"Я думаю, behemothus наверняка называл депутата N - жуликом и подхалимом"* - личное мнение.

Фразы вроде "Я считаю, что оговорка Познера про госдуру, наверняка не была случайной" мне точно попадались.

Comment: >"Я думаю, что депутат N - жулик и подхалим" - личное мнение, юридически не наказуемо.   

Сравните тогда с Вашим исходным "завтра **наверняка** будет дождь".   
  
Все понятно, можете не продолжать. Увы, судебная практика далека от Ваших розовых очков. Причем, что интересно, даже в англоязычных странах, где, во-первых, прецедент (т.е. должно бы быть больше формализации), а во-вторых, сам язык (казалось бы!)  толкает на это формализованное понимание.   
Хотя у меня вопрос не имел юридического подтекста. Хотелось понять, что может вкладывать говорящий в такую фразу. *Ибо "достало" уже*.

Comment: Я, собственно, согласился бы с чем угодно, если бы все понимали однозначно. А так, поди разберись, что говорящий хотел сказать -  и кто как его понял.

>...оговорка Познера...  
   
Ну это - в "нарочно не придумаешь".
У нас две вероятностных оценки, а тут три если не четыре: "Я считаю", "наверняка", "не была случайной". Да еще само слово "оговорка" наполовину означает случайность. 
Джае если свести до "Я думаю, что эрратив Познера точно был не случайным" (полагаю, это эквивалент, эрратив тут - "намеренная ошибка") это что-то пояснит? да ничего. Либо "точно", либо "я думаю".

Comment: Я дополнил, в ответе, по поводу градаций истинности в языке. Мысль взята отсюда http://www.adme.ru/articles/osobennosti-russkogo-mentaliteta-v-slovah-422555

В целом же, "Мысль изреченная есть ложь". С этим ничего не поделаешь. Фразы подобного типа как правило означают, что я в своём мнении уверен, но настаивать на нём не буду.

Answer (score 2):

Вот моё НЕЗАВИСИМОЕ мнение. Не буду про депутатов - лучше про дождь.

Конструкции типа "думаю, что точно [что-то произойдет]" возможны, и они логически правильны. Никто не может знать наперед, что произойдет в будущем. Любая мысль, высказанная касательно событий будущего, есть субъективная оценка говорящего. Добавляя "думаю", мы хотим подчеркнуть, что это мнение личное, основанное на собственных рассуждениях, а не, скажем, на прогнозах синоптиков.

Добавления типа *точно*, *наверняка*, *может быть* и т. п. - это обозначение степени уверенности.

Если вместо "думаю" поставить "наверное", то такая конструкция кажется мне хоть и  логически неправильной, но в разговорной речи допустимой.

Comment: Я у Вас не понял только одного. Смысл такой конструкции. Вы думаете, что произойдет или точно произойдет?  
В чем реально разница между "Я думаю, что произойдеь" и "Я думаю, что точно произойдет".  

Да, еще. Я понимание связываю с будущим временем в наименьшей степени.  
"Я думаю, что вчера точно был дождь". Что-то поменялось?

Comment: Зачем Вы ищете потайной смысл? Живая речь - это не сухой язык математических формул. Кто-то делает нелогичные высказывания, кто-то употребляет слова-паразиты, кто-то ругается матом... Искать во всём этом смысл - толочь в ступе воду.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, ссылка на источник *всегда* передаёт неуверенность говорящего, готовность выслушать возражения. Не вижу большой разницы в вариантах:

*Думаю, что (завтра пойдёт дождь | это пурпурный, а не бордовый оттенок)*.

*Думаю, что завтра наверняка пойдёт дождь*.

*Я просто уверен, что завтра пойдёт дождь!*

Во всех случаях я указываю, что это ТОЛЬКО МОЁ мнение (ну, с оттенками большей или меньшей уверенности, но всё равно - *мнение*).

Существенная разница возникает только при удалении ссылки на источник:

*Это бордовый цвет!* (вы что, будете спорить?!) - уже не мнение, а претензия на истину в последней инстанции.

Comment: >ну, с оттенками большей или меньшей уверенности, но всё равно - мнение...    
  
Вы полагаете, что "Я думаю" этот источник? Тогда о какой степени уверенности идет речь? Ведь в таком случае "я думаю" и "наверняка" никак не пересекаются - и не противоречат друг другу. 
"Наверняка пойдет дождь" - некое высказывание, содержащее объективную оценку уровня знаний, а "я думаю" - личное отношение к этому высказыванию. Получается, что предыдущие ораторы правы... Но я крайне сомневаюсь, что кто-то из реально употребляющих подобный оборот вкладывает в него подобный смысл.

Comment: Модификатор "наверняка" точно так же, как и "Я думаю", указывает на сомнение говорящего (утверждается не бесспорная истина, а только мнение).

Это _точно (наверяка)_ бордовый цвет!

_Я уверен, что_ это бордовый цвет!

Здесь выделенные части, по-моему, вполне контекстно синонимичны (в указанном мной смысле). Без этих частей фраза будет звучать более уверенно, _безапелляционно_ (а наличие как "Я думаю", так и "наверняка" допускает возможность апелляции, оспаривания).

Answer (score 0):

1) Нет (здесь слово "точно" указывает на то, что слово "думаю" в значении "уверен").
2) Смотря кто думает. Как можно точно знать, что будет завтра?
3) Заменить на синонимы можно, но опять  остается тот же вопрос: "Как можно точно знать, что будет завтра?"
4) Да.

Answer (score 0):

Пока не закрываю, ни один ответ меня не удовлетворяет

Answer (score 0):

Выскажу своё предположение.

- 1. Нет, на мой взгляд, не верна.
- 3. Мне кажется, что когда некоторые, не подумав хорошо над своими словами, так говорят, они невольно смешивают предположение (*я думаю ≈ мне кажется*, но не "я считаю") с уверенностью, подразумевая что-то среднее, а точнее *большую степень уверенности.* Тогда похожей конструкцией будет: *Я почти уверен, что завтра пойдёт дождь.*
     Повторюсь, что это даже не мнение, а предположение. Допускаю, что даже сам могу так сказать случайно, и, даже если сразу замечу это и поправлюсь, возможно, не пойму, почему я так сказал и что хотел вложить в это. Только представляя себе такую ситуацию или пытаясь представить себя на месте того, кто так говорит, мне показалось, что я буду иметь в виду то, что написал.
- 4. В случае "точно" в смысле *"на 100%"* ответы не зависят от того, что в скобках, если "точно" употребляется с глаголом в будущем времени и подразумевается какое-то действие, событие в будущем. А если имеется в виду "точно" в смысле *"правильно",* как в Вашем примере с *"точно ответил",* или, например, *"точно описал обстановку", "точно выполнил данные мне инструкции"* и т. д., тогда, конечно, конструкция становится верной, а остальные ответы очевидными. То же и в случае первого значения *(на 100%)* для примера: "Я думаю, что точно он не знал, как поведёт себя, попади он в такую ситуацию". Примеров, подобных последнему, можно придумать множество. Такие конструкции, безусловно, верны.