# Нужно ли "мол"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

на сайте "Грама" есть такой вопрос и ответ:

Вопрос 8001:    Какие знаки необходимо ставить в предложении: Приехала моя подруга и говорит() Нужна () мол () твоя помощь - денег нет ()?

Ответ:   Можно поставить такие знаки: «Приехала моя подруга и говорит: нужна, мол, твоя помощь - денег нет».

Но разве нужно "мол" в данном случае?

И еще вопрос и ответ:

Вопрос 8281:    Помогите, пожалуйста, с пунктуацией: 
Более отрицательно, () чем положительно итоги выборов оценивают...

Ответ:    Более отрицательно, чем положительно итоги выборов оценивают...

Разве не так должно быть:Более отрицательно, чем положительно, итоги выборов оценивают...

Answer (score 3):

"Мол" обозначает, что чужая речь передаётся не буквально. Поэтому без кавычек и с маленькой буквы (ответ верен). А вот во втором вопросе стилистически неудачно "Более", поскольку сомнения человека типа "в ту или иную сторону оценивать" не имеют количественного измерения: это выбор, к которому склоняются. Правильно: "*Скорее* положительно, чем отрицательно".

Comment: Вообще-то "мол" синонимично "дескать" ("-де") и "якобы" и не не сет семантики именно "неточной"  передачи чужой речи. Может быть и своей и/или буквальной передачей. Тут смысл именно в том, что слова в том или ином виде уже были сказаны. Интересно, что Лопатин трактует "мол" как частицу. А Кузнецов просто как вводное. ВидимоЮ какая-то недоговоренность в понимании все-таки есть, отсюда сомнения в пунктуации.

Answer (score 1):

> Ответ: *Более отрицательно, чем положительно итоги выборов оценивают...*
>
> Разве не так должно быть: *Более отрицательно, чем положительно, итоги выборов >оценивают.*

Очень неудачная конструкция фразы. Тут надо или весь контекст приводить *"более отрицательно, чем положительно итоги выборов оценивают [пять из десяти опрошенных]"* или срочно менять порядок слов.

А запятая вроде бы факультативна. От степени обособленности этого "чем положительно", при такой конструкции фразы она, да, желательна.

Касательно слова "более". Да, здесь более употребительно и более стилистически верно было бы слово "скорее". Но это не вопрос пунктуации.

Comment: Артем, я не буду сейчас откатывать вашу правку, но мое обособление "вроде бы" (если относится ко всей фразе, а не к сказуемому) - это как раз к разговору о бренности разделения подобных слов на частицы и вводные. Проблема, видимо, восходит к Розенталю, который забыл или поленился упомянуть её/его в списке возможных вводных слов.  Вообще это тема для отдельного вопроса.

Comment: Мне оно совсем не кажется вводным. Но в любом случае простите, если Вам не нравится так, давайте сделаем по-Вашему.

Comment: Да нет, не надо. Коли уж Вам глаз резануло, найдутся еще. Лучше в другом месте обсудим. Здесь достаточно упомянут один из главных тезисов сторонников обособления. "Вроде" ("вроде бы", "вроде бы как" и т.п.) синонимично "кажется" и т.п., которое однозначно признается вводным всеми. А вы, видимо, рассматриваете его с несколько другим акцентом., в наречном значении при сказуемом ("предположительно", "вероятно")., каковое обычно не требует обособления. Если вы эти случае не различаете, то и смысла нет разбирать.

Comment: В данном случае я воспринимаю "вроде" как "кажется", то есть из вашего комментария оно получается вводным. Теперь я тоже начинаю воспринимать его как вводное. Видимо, действует память, что его не обособляют, и поэтому с запятыми режет глаз. Хотя, если его все признают вводным и будут выделять, я к этому привыкну наверняка. Но почему-то его не хочется выделять (и я не надеюсь, что не только в силу привычки). Хотелось бы услышать все доводы за то, что это слово не вводное, и если они окажутся неубедительными, тогда надо будет признать, что вы правы.

Comment: Это не из моего комментария, это основной (один из) довод тех, кто полагает обособление возможным.  Слушайте, давайте, правда откроем отдельный вопрос, коли он того заслуживает.  Я только Розенталя найду, там где он дает список вводных и оканчивает его "и т.д". А что входит в это и т.д. - не уточняет, хотя очень похоже, что "вроде бы" в этот ряд вполне вписывается.

Comment: Давайте откроем вопрос, я за! :) Вы спросите?

Comment: И прокомментируйте мой ответ на свой вопрос всё-таки, пожалуйста, как сможете, интересно, что скажете. http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/20309/%D0%94%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE

Comment: Ну да, открою, только чуть позже. Что касается вашего ответа, это я просто не очень понимаю, что там комментировать.  Столько времени прошло. Мне самому надо вспомнить контекст, ситуацию, которая у меня этот вопрос вызвала.

Comment: Странно. Просто вы меньше года назад, через полтора года после создания вопроса, написали, что вопрос открыт и вы ещё ждете на него хорошего ответа. Я думал, что и до сих пор вас он интересует.

Comment: Там новый ответ появился, я его и прокомментировал. В том смысле, что ответа приемлемого так и нет. Не помню, чтобы я именно "ждал", видимо неудачного выразился.

Comment: У меня видно, что все кроме меня ответили в течение трёх дней. И вы написали ответом, что приемлемого ответа нет, в начале года. Про "ждёте" я по-своему перефразировал.)) Ну да ладно, проехали.